# Async validate single redux form field, but not on submit

Tags: redux-form

## Question

How can one build a async validation on a single form field that also can trigger filed level errors, but without using a asyncValidation that also triggers onSubmit?

## Background to question

I have a Redux form where the user can choose to:

a) Input adress details by hand

b) Fill in their social security number and fetch all details from a API and get the redux form fields prefilled (wohoo, time saved!)

c) Being 100% anonymous by checking a checkbox which removed all personal details fields.

Given this kind of setup a asyncValidator that triggers onSubmit and onBlur seems tricky, i don't want them to trigger more than once if a get the desired details and the form get pre-filled. But if user submits a invalid social security number I want to trigger a field error.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to validate a single field, you can pass a prop validate
with an array of validation functions, that will return false if its valid, and a string error if invalid based on your logic. and will prevent submission, or will show an error on submittion.

```
const required = (value) => (value ? false : 'Required')
const isSSN = (value) => (willBeTrueIfSSN ? false : 'Invalid SSN')
<Field name="ssn" validate={[isSSN, required]} {...rest} />
```

some good examples in the redux-form docs:
https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/